# If an object is free on two sets, then are those two sets isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a concrete category and let $A$ be an object in $\mathscr{C}$. If $A$ is free on two sets $X$ and $X'$, then are $X$ and $X'$ isomorphic? This question came up to me because this is a common result for categories of abelian groups and vector spaces, but I am not sure if this holds in general.

Comment: Try looking up "invariant basis number".